# I have a css file in vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/style.css in my own module but it is not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I have a css file in `web/css/style.css` in my own module . but it is not working . i have called it in my `vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/xmlfile` . 
Note : I don't want to add it in theme css i want to add it in my own module .

```
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: have you put css file in web/css/styles.css in module ?

Comment: yes vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/style.css

Comment: did you run deploy static command also ?

Comment: yes , cache flush also .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are step you can take to check your css is loading.

1. Make sure layout file name is correct
2. added the xml tag `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
3. using page_configuration.xsd

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    </page>
   ```
4. deploy content **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
5. clear magento cache **php bin/magento cache:clean**
6. make sure file located in `pub/static/frontend/spacename/themename/en_US/modulename/`
7. Use  Incognito mode in browser to avoid browser cache problem

Comment: static-content deployed .. cache:flush ... pub/static/frontend/spacename/themename/en_US/modulename/ has style..css file . but it is empty ... but still no effect .

Comment: @samairali remove css file and generate content again.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your theme you are using, put css file on your theme
2. check xml file defined by utf-8 format
3. try add code `<update handle="your_xmlfile"/>` to your xml file
4. make sure your store deployed, cleared cache, cleared host cache ...
5. setup correct permission for your store folder